# Python with 2 continue in a while

Tags: python, while-loop, exception, continue

I tried exception handling and got stuck in my first program, in this program my first continue in while is working but 2nd one is not continuing the loop

```
print("hello to divide")
o = "y"
while o == "y":
    try:
        x = int(input("enter first no. = "))
        y = int(input("enter second no. = "))
    except:
        print("please enter numeric value")
        continue
    try:
        z = x/y
        print(str(x) +"/"+str(y)+"="+str(z))
    except:
        print("please do not divide with 0(zero)")
        continue

    finally:
        o = input("do you want to do it again (y/n)? = ")
```

The second except is working fine but after printing message it jumps to finally statement

please help ???

Comment: I tried formatting your code, but you should make sure it accurately reflects what you actually have.

Comment: Why are you using continue ?

Comment: Yes, because `finally` is *always* executed. That's the whole point.

Comment: thank you very much i'll make sure it wont happen again  @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: i m using continue so the while loop would again execute and before finally would execute

Comment: as if finally always execute then why first continue works and re-initialize while when error in 1st except encountered @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @aekanshupanchal because the `finally` is attached to the *second* `try` clause.

Comment: ok i got it now thank you sir its a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions):

> A *finally clause* is always executed before leaving the `try`
>   statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception
>   has occurred in the `try` clause and has not been handled by an
>   `except` clause (or it has occurred in an `except` or `else` clause),
>   it is re-raised after the `finally` clause has been executed. The
>   `finally` clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other
>   clause of the try statement is left via a **`break`, `continue` or
>   `return`** statement. A more complicated example:

I'm pretty sure you just want:

```
print("hello to divide")
o = "y"
while o == "y":
    try:
        x = int(input("enter first no. = "))
        y = int(input("enter second no. = "))
    except:
        print("please enter numeric value")
        continue
    try:
        z = x/y
        print(str(x) +"/"+str(y)+"="+str(z))
    except:
        print("please do not divide with 0(zero)")
        continue

    o = input("do you want to do it again (y/n)? = ")
```